# How to handle params validation both in JS and Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, validation

I am wondering what will be the better way to handle params validation both in the frontend (JS/React) and in our backend (Rails/Mongoid). I was thinking doing validation directly in the Rails controllers as almost everything is optional, it's for an API, and there are numerous parameters. Mongoid also populates each `field` entry with a `null` value even if the field is not needed.

I was thinking have a config file like this:

```
search_engine_a:
  q:
    required: true
    explanation: Query to be searched
    error: Query is required
  num:
    explanation: Number of results
    type: Integer
    interval: 0_100
    error: Needs to be an integer between 0 and 100
  start
    explanation: Results offset
    type: Integer
    error: Needs to be an integer between 0 and 100
  ...
search_engine_b:
  wd:
    required: true
    explanation: Query to be searched
    ...
  ...
...
```

Then have some code in Ruby on Rails to parse this to use against our API requests and provide the error message if needed. Same thing in JS for the frontend. Parse the same configuration file and use it provide errors and explanations in our API playground interface.

Does this make sense or am I reinventing the wheel?

[EDIT] To give a more precise idea, it's for this API: https://serpapi.com/search-api

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using [`json-schema`](https://json-schema.org/)? There are plenty of plugins to [validate it server side](https://ajv.js.org/), [typescript integration](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema), and probably lots more I don't know about!